# TimeDelay error in android using thread

Tags: android, multithreading, text-to-speech, timedelay

As i am making an app, there is problem in delay of the function,

Firstly I am using thread as a timer and I am also using an animation function....

When the timer ends it starts TextToSpeech and in background the animation of Images works continuosly...

After TTS ends it again starts the timer and after a fixed time timer stops and  TTS is started..This works on continuosly..

But due to this there is problem in delay of TTS and it does not work exactly after the timer stops....and it takes some time....

So what should I do to stop this delay??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your timer shouldnt have a fixed value, but a calculated one. If you want it to fire at a fixed internal (timeFI), you should calculate the processing time in the TTS (timeTTS) and set the timer "sleep time" = (timeFI - timeTTS)

Comment: is there any procedure to calculate the process time of TTS ??

Comment: @poSEID0n, Im not sure, but worst case would be to get the time before and after and use the diff.